# Sata to USB3 Cable - Data Only, no power

Tags: usb, sata

I'm trying to find a type of cable, that will let me connect a hard drive's data line to USB3

The drives are 3.5, and I hope to supply their power with a dedicated PSU, all the Sata to USB cables I find on Amazon have wide ends that try to cover both power and data.

Does anyone know of a cable that will only connect the data line from Sata to USB3? Is there a hardware limitation that I'm not realizing?

Comment: Hello there. The issue lies with the fact that most USB3 adapters are for recent 2.5 drives. USB can only give 5V, so the 12V needs an external supply. You could simply buy one with its own power supply? You aren't going to save any costs and time by buying one without a supply.  If you really want your own supply, these are the only ones available afaik: https://www.amazon.com/AGPtek-Drive-Adapter-Converter-External/dp/B00BIE996S/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=usb2+sata&qid=1581797487&sr=8-3

Answer (score 1):

Start with a [USB 3 to SATA III combi cable](https://www.startech.com/HDD/Adapters/usb-3-1-gen-2-adapter-cable-2-5-sata-drives~USB31CSAT3CB).

Add a [short SATA male-female cable](https://www.ebay.com/i/233429373289) to the drive end of the combi cable.

Now you're free to handle the drive power requirements, however you wish.